# GraphQL using a field as argument in the same query

Tags: graphql

I have constructed the following query in Gitlab's GraphQL Explorer to show my question:

https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer

```
{
  project(fullPath: "gitlab-org/gitlab") {
    name
    repository {
      rootRef
    }
    mergeRequests(state: merged, targetBranches: "master") {
      nodes {
        sourceBranch
        targetBranch
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is using the value of **repository { rootRef }** as the argument for **targetBranches**.

Something like this:
`mergeRequests(state: merged, targetBranches: repository { rootRef }) {`

Can it be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Nope, you'll need two queries I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah :( was hoping for some magic that I hadn't found yet. Thanks though.